# Facebook 3.0 is not working, Android

Tags: android, facebook

I am integrating new Facebook SDK(3.0.1) in my app.So I am using Facebook code for login but everytime after input credential a "Web page not available" page is shown. Even Sample Application given in facebook SDk is not working and is showing same web page. Somebody help me in finding out the solution.  I have gone through this link also,but this solution is not working ---> [Facebook integration on Android fbconnect broken link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880622/facebook-integration-on-android-fbconnect-broken-link)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The solution is to update your Facebook app to the latest version.